# Configure exim to use remote smtp without authentication

Tags: exim

I have a dedicated server with exim4 on it. I have configured exim4 to always use Amazon's SMTP server (`mail.mydomainname.com`) for email delivery.

I do have access credentials, but I want to know if its possible to force exim to not authenticate the Amazon server credentials.

I get the below error as I have not added the creds in the `passwd.client` file.

```
  ** root@mydomainname.com R=smarthost T=remote_smtp_smarthost H=********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************": SMTP error from remote mail server after MAIL FROM:<>: 530 Authentication required
```

Is there any directive that can be added in the `remote_smtp_smarthost` or anywhere in the `exim4.conf.template` to bypass the authentication?

Comment: usually look for backup mx or a relay host depends on the use case